# how to auto populate in excel written numbers

Tags: excel, matlab

this is a very simple question, but I can not find a way arround it. I am working ona MATLAB project and I need to convert numbers from 1 to 1000 to the written form I.E(one, two, three, four...) since I do not know how to do this in MATLAB I was just going to autopopulate the numbers in MS Excel and import the data directly into MATLAB. My problem is I do not know neither how to autopulate numbers in their written form in Excel since it does not work as I would normally do. I.E :Typing one, two, three, four in separate cells; selcting the values and dragging until I hit 1000. Once I start dragging it just repeats the values over and over. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue either in MATLAB or MS Excel. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To find the auto-populate lists in Excel, go to Options>Advanced>General>Edit Custom Lists

As you can see below, written form numbers are not included in these lists, which explains why they do not autofill when you drag down.

[image: Custom Lists]

As pnuts alluded to in the comments, a good way around this in Excel would be to create a custom function that will generate a written form number for any numeral cell value. This has already been done by Microsoft support and is very easy to implement by pasting the code on this link into the Visual Basic Editor in your workbook. (credit to pnuts)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213360/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-english-words-in-excel

Once you've done that, you just put your numbers from MATLAB into column A, then paste this formula into B1 and drag down.

```
=SpellNumber(A1)
```